# Checking existance of the record and Inserting in MongoDB using Stored Function

Tags: javascript, c#, mongodb, stored-functions, mongo-shell

Is it good practice to call stored function through c# for inserting a record before checking for its existence or do the same operation through linq in c#?

for e.g

My function is below

```
function(productid, json) {   
    var exists = db.zProduct.find({"ProductId":productid, "Combinations": { $elemMatch: json }}).count()
    if(exists == 0){
        db.zProductMongoModel.insertOne({"ProductId":productid, "Combinations":json })
        return ("New Document Created")
        }
}
```

The above code works fine if I call the function though C# but i read from [[https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/]](http://Docs)[2](http://Mongodb%20Doc) 
that Do not store application logic in the database.
Someone pls advise.

Comment: Are you using the C# mongodb driver?

Comment: Yes I'm using mongodb c sharp driver